# How to append corresponding html to li item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi this is my html code

```
<li class="item"> <img src="te.jpeg"/> <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="je.jpeg"/> <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="mse.jpeg"/> <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="tdr.jpeg"/> <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="chk.jpeg"/> <li>
```

Here i want to append a

item with different content using jquery please see below ,

```
<li class="item"> <img src="te.jpeg"/>  <p class="item-name name1" >First de </p> <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="je.jpeg"/>  <p class="item-name name2" >second des </p> <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="mse.jpeg"/> <p class="item-name name3" >third des </p>  <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="tdr.jpeg"/> <p class="item-name name4" >Fourth de </p> <li>
<li class="item"> <img src="chk.jpeg"/> <p class="item-name name5" >Fifth des </p> <li>
```

Please help to do this using jquery .

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Add that code as well.

Comment: is your list of li is fixed??

Comment: yes. please help to solve this

Comment: `<li>` should be closed with `</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var htmls = ['First de','second des','third des','fourth des'];
var classes = ['class1','class2','class3','class4'];

var i = 0;
$('.item').each(function(){
 $(this).children('img').after('<p class="'+classes[i]+'">'+htmls[i]+'</p>');
 i++;

})
```

use loop for each append

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li img[src="te.jpeg"]').parent().append('<p class="item-name name1" >First de </p>');
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w3u5mh7/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var className = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4,', 'name5' ];
var des = ['First des', 'Second des', 'Third des', 'Fourth des', 'Fifth des' ];

$("li.item").each(function( index ) {
  $(this).append(`<p class="item-name ${className[index]}" >${des[index]}</p>`);
});
```